# Why is $F(t)=\hbar\frac{dk}{dt}$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics, solid-state-physics

I know $F(t)=m\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=\frac{dp(t)}{dt}$.

However, the force on a electron can be written as $F(t)=\hbar\frac{dk}{dt}$. Why is that?

Isn't $k$ just a constant, $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$? I.e. no function of $t$, $k\neq k(t)$?

Comment: For a plane wave, $p = \hbar k$. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: @ DanielSank Yes, thanks! I wondering how you can take the time derivative of $k$ if $k$ is just a scalar? Isn't $k$ suppost to be a function of time?

Comment: @JDoeDoe If $k$ is constant, then $p$ is constant. In other words, if there is a force, $k$ and $\lambda$ change.

Comment: @ Jahan Claes Hmm, but isn't $k$ always a constant, $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$? Or is $k(t)=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda (t)}$?